# Does the Eclipse Web browser implement the "Same Origin policy"?

Tags: eclipse, http, same-origin-policy

Does the Eclipse Web browser implement the "Same Origin policy"?

I have a small web client that makes some HTTP request to a server but the problem is that the server is not on the same domain. I am working on a mandriva with no admin rights and I am using the defaults web browsers which are Firefox and Epiphany (which is based on Firefox). Since I know that Firefox restricts this possibility, I would like to know if it is the same in the Eclipse Web Browser. I tried to make some requests but nothing happens.